# What is the probability of rolling 3 different pairs with seven dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

for example one outcome can be this :

(1,1,2,2,3,3,4)

My answer is different compared to the book

**This is how i solve it:**

$$\frac{\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}}{6^7} $$

**The book solves it like this:**

$$\frac{\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}}{6^7}=0.135  $$

am i wrong?

isn't this outcome :(1,1,2,2,3,3,4) different compared to this :(2,2,1,1,3,3,4) ?

Comment: You mean probability not odds.

Comment: That is correct, sorry my English is not so good, i didn't know they were not the same

Comment: As a native English speaker I would have no problem understanding the term "odds". It's not as technical but I think most people know it's another word for probability.

Comment: Would $(1,1,2,2,3,3,3)$ be a possible positive outcome, or does the triple, which contains a double, disqualify it?

Comment: It seems from the book answer, that they don't want to count two pairs and a triple. However, to figure out where you went astray, we would need to see the reasoning behind the answer you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a justification of the book's answer:

Choose the three values for the pairs from the six possible values on the dice in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.  Choose the value of the singleton from the remaining three values in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways.  For the three pairs, there are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways for the smallest value to appear on two of the seven dice, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways for the middle value to appear on two of the other five dice, and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways for the largest value to appear on two of the other three dice.  The remaining die shows the singleton value.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$
favorable outcomes.

In your attempt, you count each favorable outcome six times, once for each way you designate one of the three pairs as your first pair, another pair as your second pair, and the remaining pair as your third pair.  The order in which the pairs are selected does not matter.  Notice that 
$$6\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2} = \binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so there is no difference between (2,2,1,1,3,3,4)  and (1,1,2,2,3,3,4)  ? both are same right ?

Comment: it is different here, because you are then dividing by $6^7$ - example - two dice, 36 outcomes, but there are two ways to get 1 and 2 (1,2) is not the same as (2,1) if you then do $\frac{2}{36} = \frac{1}{18}$ as the probability

Comment: @EdaiBossinShid The outcomes $(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4)$ and $(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)$ are different since, for instance, $2$ appears on the first die in one outcome and $1$ appears on that die in the other.  However, we have accounted for that by choosing which dice the $1$s appear on, the $2$s appear on, and the $3$s appear on with the factor $\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$.   However, there are only $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to count which three numbers appear on the pairs not $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}$ since the order in which the pairs are selected does not matter.

Comment: But considering we have $6^7$ as denominator it means each dice is unique right? therefore doesn't that make the order of which pair is getting which number important? for example if we have 2 pairs, then shouldn't (1,1),(2,2) be different compared to (2,2),(1,1) therefore making the order important?

Comment: You are correct that each die is unique.  We account for the order by choosing which dice receive which pair.  The factor of $\binom{7}{2}$ selects which dice receive the pair with the smallest number.  The factor of $\binom{5}{2}$ selects which dice receive the pair with the middle number.  The factor of $\binom{3}{2}$ selects which dice receive the pair with the largest number.  In your example $(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)$, we first choose the multiset $\{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4\}$ with the factor $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}$, then placing them with the factor $\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig now i get it!! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether a triple covers a double, we can include the red term:
$$
\color{#C00}{\underbrace{\overbrace{\ \ \ \binom{6}{2}\ \ \ }^\text{$2$ pair}\overbrace{\ \ \ \binom{4}{1}\ \ \ }^\text{$1$ triple}\overbrace{\vphantom{\binom{6}{2}}\ \frac{7!}{2!2!3!}\ }^\text{rearrangements}}_{\sim4.5\%\text{ of }6^7}+}\underbrace{\overbrace{\ \ \ \binom{6}{3}\ \ \ }^\text{$3$ pair}\overbrace{\ \ \ \binom{3}{1}\ \ \ }^\text{$1$ singleton}\overbrace{\vphantom{\binom{6}{2}}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}}^\text{$\ \ $rearrangements}}_{\sim13.5\%\text{ of }6^7}
$$
Note that $\frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}=\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$ and $\frac{7!}{2!2!3!}=\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}$, so the answer, if not accepting a triple, would be
$$
\left.\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}\middle/6^7\right.\approx13.5\%
$$
which matches the book answer.